# If LILO is installed to the MBR, is there any bootloader code in the VBR?

Tags: linux, slackware

My understanding of LILO is that it can be installed to either the a VBR or the MBR.

If I have a 'DOS' MBR, and install LILO to my Linux VBR, I envision the boot process to look like this:

```
MBR -> VBR (LILO) -> Linux
```

However, If I install LILO to the MBR, what does the boot process look like?  Is the VBR bootloader code still used?  For example, does the boot process look like this:

```
MBR (LILO) -> Linux
```

Or like this:

```
MBR (LILO) -> VBR (LILO) -> Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

No, if LILO is installed into the MBR, there will be no need to use the VBR at all.

However, do not assume that the whole of LILO will be contained within the boot record. The MBR/VBR will only contain the first part of LILO: the rest will be read from file /boot/boot.b, using pre-stored block numbers.